# Using SMOTE for imbalanced data

Tags: smote

While doing the SMOTE , i get the following error.
"Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"
the Below is my code 
bal.m <- SMOTE(Default ~., (LD.train), perc.over =300,k=5,  perc.under =200)

Am i mssing something.PLease guide